# Auto detect font form PDF. Download font and display text in that font on website?

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a [website](https://iamebook.com). Where we upload ebooks. While upload a PDF we extract text from PDF. That is working perfectly fine. I have to display that text to my website. This is working fine until PDF is in another language which is not common for browsers. Like Hindi, Punjabi, Japaneses etc. At that time it extracted text from PDF but that is random English text not in same font. When I copy that text to word and select it to same font in word that will become exact same.

So I need some code in ASP.net core 3.1 MVC to make this process automatic. Like when I extract text from PDF it can also extract text format. And download it if not exists and when I load text to website it will appear in good font. We can also use JavaScript, jQuery, and CSS.

Comment: It sounds like a font and encoding problem to me. Take for example, if you extracted Japanese, will it display correctly if in the HTML you use a font with Japanese characters like the [Google Noto fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP)?

Comment: Yes that what I need but these things either be automate or something so that I know that new font need to download, And I will add to website